# How to add a Combobox to MenuBar using Eclipse E4

Tags: eclipse, combobox, e4

Is it possible to add a combo box to main MenuBar, how do i achieve this using Eclipse E4 ?

Comment: What do you mean by `MenuBar`? Do you mean the `Main Menu` or do you mean the `TrimBars > Window Trim > Toolbar`

Comment: I meant, 'Main Menu' ; Trimmed Window -> Main Menu

Comment: I don't think this is possible.